Single click files to open and not letting them be automatically selected on hover
In windows explorer, I want to

Single click files to open them instead of double clicking
Not have files automatically selected when I hover them with the mouse

How?
edit
If I have single click enabled then clicking the file will run/edit it. If I Ctrl click the file, it will become selected without having it automatially selected on hover. In other the system will not be rendered unusable by removing the automatic selection.

You cannot. Because if you could, there would not be any way anymore to work with a single file.

I don't understand what you mean by "Not have files automatically selected when I hover them with the mouse", normally when you hover, nothing is selected. For single click, go to Options, on the Click items as follows, select  Single-click to open an item (point to select).

I agree with @ReddyLutonadio on this one, hover over files shouldn't select them, this highlights a probable issue with mouse buttons or digitiser if using touch screen. Also personally I wouldn't advise of enabling single click to open files, this can lead to user error when working with an anomaly files etc.

I wrote a touch screen driver that this was a requirement for.  Select on hover.  Possibly the driver but I doubt it.

When I hover a file with the mouse, it takes a couple of seconds and it becomes selected by itself. That is only when single clicking has been enabled but I see no reason. @ReddyLutonadio

Microsoft designed it that either, you have single click to open and hover to select, or single click to select and double click to open. There's no way to do single click to open in explorer itself. If it is only for one folder, you could look into a launcher, but otherwise, not possible with just explorer itself.

@AndersLindén some assumptions will be made by those trying to help you. Giving limited information and the behaviour you are seeing will lead to most thinking outside of the box. You haven't stated if its desktop or laptop and thus a track pad could also be at fault. This is very much an XY issue, your trying to work around symptoms rather than resolving the root cause.

I mae an edit to the question @CraftyB

Have you looked at the Windows settings for it? What is available, and where does it fall short?

I've never heard or seen stuff being selected on hover. Is that confusion because hover gets visually highlighted as well? That's not a selection. That's a hover highlight - to indicate an interactable element.

Try to hover, wait a second, then the file will appear selected and pressing delete will delete the file. @Kissaki
